# Find the Taylor series centered at $4$ for $f^{(n)}(4)=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{3^n(n+1)}$, and its convergence radius and interval.

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, taylor-expansion, power-series

I was given the following problem:

> Find the Taylor series centered at $4$ for $f^{(n)}(4)=\frac{(-1)^nn!}{3^n(n+1)}$ and its convergence radius.

I have an upcoming test, I'm practicing and was wondering if someone could validate my solution. This is what I did.

---

We know around $x=4$

$$
f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nn!}{3^n(n+1)} \frac{1}{n!}(x-4)^n= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{3^n(n+1)} (x-4)^n
$$

Let $a_n:=\frac{(-1)^n (x-4)^n}{3^n(n+1)}$. Then

$$\begin{align}
|\frac{(-1)^{n+1} (x-4)^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}(n+2)} \cdot \frac{3^n(n+1)}{(-1)^n(x-4)^n}| &= \frac{1}{3}\Big(\frac{n+1}{n+2}\Big)|x-4| \\ &=\frac{1}{3}\Big(\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{1+\frac{2}{n}}\Big)|x-4| \\ &\rightarrow\frac{1}{3}|x-4| \space \text{if} \space n \rightarrow \infty\end{align}
$$

Notice that

$$
\frac{1}{3}|x-4| <1 \iff |x-4| < 3
$$

Also, see that

$$
|x-4|<3 \iff -3<x-4<3 \iff 1<x<7
$$

implies the series is convergent at least for $x \in (1, 7)$. We can test the bounds of this interval and see that if $x=1$ then the series becomes

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{3^n(n+1)} (-3)^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n(-1)^n 3^n}{3^n(n+1)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$$

which diverges (*harmonic series*). If $x=7$ then the series becomes

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{3^n(n+1)} (3)^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}
$$

which converges (*alternating harmonic series*). This is sufficient to conclude $R=3, I=(1, 7]$.

---

Is this correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is correct, well done !

Comment: Thank you @Fred!